# Estimate about interior elliptic regularity!

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the paper Monotonicity for Elliptic Equations in Unbounded Lipschitz Domains - Berestycki - Caffarelli - Niremberg, they use the estimate "obtained by interior elliptic regularity": if $B=B_\rho(y)\subset\Omega$ and $|x-y|\leq\rho/2$, then
$$|u(x)-u(y)|\leq \widehat C\max_Bu\cdot\left(\frac{|x-y|}{\rho}\right)^\gamma+\widehat C\rho^{2-\gamma}|x-y|^\gamma,$$
for $\gamma\in(0,1]$. Someone can help me to obtain this estimate? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why they write $\gamma$ there. Observe that $\gamma\to a^\gamma$ is a decreasing function of $\gamma$ for any fixed base $0<a<1$. Here we have 
$$
\frac{|x-y|}{\rho}\le \frac12 
$$
and since the right hand side is
$$
\widehat C\max_Bu\cdot\left(\frac{|x-y|}{\rho}\right)^\gamma+\widehat C\rho^{2}\left(\frac{|x-y|}{\rho}\right)^\gamma
$$
it is a decreasing function of $\gamma$. Thus, it suffices to prove the estimate for $\gamma=1$. Theorem 3.9 in Gilbarg-Trudinger (used with $\Omega=B$) gives the gradient bound 
$$
 \sup_{B_{\rho/2}(y)} |\nabla u| \le \frac{C}{\rho}\left( \sup_B |u| + \rho^2 \sup_B |\Delta u|\right) 
$$
Recalling that $\Delta u$ is uniformly bounded, and using the mean value theorem, we obtain 
$$
|u(x)-y(y)| \le \frac{C}{\rho}|x-y|\left( \sup_B |u| + \rho^2 \sup_B |\Delta u|\right) 
$$
for $x\in B_{\rho/2}(y)$.

Comment: The $\gamma$ is used to prove that $u$ is Hölder Continuous. In the paper, we use this estimate to prove this. Can I use this estimate argument for each $\gamma\in(0,1]$? 5PM, you answered an another question to me here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284506/a-problem-about-convergence but I have one more doubt, about the uniform convergence of the Laplacian (the $C^2$-convergence). Do you know what implies this convergence? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I didn't understand why the right hand side is a decreasing function of $\gamma$. Could you explain it?

Comment: @JoséCarlos I updated my answer with more detail. I'll get back to the convergence question..

Comment: Thank you very much @5PM.

Comment: I am waiting your help in the other question @5PM! Thank you!